# rsync'd directories not equal

Tags: rsync, md5sum

I run "rsync -av /src /tgt" and afterwards, to check if source and target are identical,
i run "tar -cf - dir | md5sum" (where dir is either "src" or "tgt") in expectation that both hashes are the same.
But they are not. Why?

Comment: There's no particular necessity for `tar` to archive the files in a given order, and if the order changes, naturally the hash of the archive will change. https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120143/70524